# Systemd service for a ruby rake job and environmental variables

Tags: linux, systemd, environment-variables

I have many environmental variables that are required to run my ruby rake job. This job will be supervised by systemd.

How can I export all the environmental variables?

And also export them in such a way so that **only my systemd service** will see them, if this possible.

Here's my service which has only a single environmental variable in it:

```
  $ cat /etc/systemd/system/my_service.service 
  [Unit]
  After=syslog.target
  Requires=mysql.service

  [Service]
  WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/my_app/app1
  ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc 'source /home/ubuntu/.profile && bundle exec rake jobs:job1'
  Restart=on-abort
  RestartSec=10
  StandardOutput=syslog
  StandardError=syslog
  SyslogIdentifier=app1_bg_jobs
  User=ubuntu
  Group=ubuntu
  Environment=RAILS_ENV=staging

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I don't want to use the key `Environment` because there're many variables and some may contain `$HOME` which won't be resolved in systemd